# IIS Removal of Server information header

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, asp-classic

I have written the following url rewrite module to remove server version information in response header.

```
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>        
    <rule name="Remove Server header">
      <match filterByTags="None" serverVariable="" pattern=".+" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
    </rule>        
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

This is working fine in normal flows.
However when an error page(like 500 or 404) is rendered I am able to see the IIS version information.

I need to know how to handle this rewrite for error pages as well.
Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Think this type of server configuration question is better served by [sf]

Comment: `However when an error page(like 500 or 404)` when you see error in __local__ network?

Comment: I am intentionally inducing error either by changing the verb to OPTIONS or hitting a page that does not exit.

Answer (score 0):

why not just create a custom error page, that way yo can make it look however you want

Comment: Yes I have create custom pages. But when the custom page is loaded(due to induced exceptions), the rewrite is failing and I could see IIS information in headers